# Plugin for Explorer to expand folders in the main window

Tags: windows

I was wondering is there any plugin for Windows 7 that allows you to expand a folder without actually clicking into the folder?

Basically the functionality that is in the navigation pane **but not for the main explorer window**...

OS X and Ubuntu both have this feature, anyone know of a plugin for explorer or a registry tweak to add this functionality???

Here are the screenshots of OS X and Ubuntu so you know exactly of what I'm talking about...

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes there is. mouse-over the folder on the left side (folder list).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not in the navigation pane, the main window

Comment: then you have to make your own explorer program instead. I think no "plugin" can modify this behavior.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd stake high odds that there's a plugin to add this functionality like classicshell.sourceforge.net OR freelaunchbar.com. I reckon there are other people who have wanted this functionality...

Comment: it's not worth to make such plugins, as it may be disabled by future Windows Update.